# Как создать zip-архив с паролем и добавить в него случайные фотографии?

Tags: python

Я сделал это так, но на архиве нет пароля

```
create_password = random.randbytes(20)
    for i in range(rand_photo):
        file = ['photo/*.jpg']
        images = glob.glob(random.choice(file))
        random_img = random.choice(images)
        # compressing file
        with pyzipper.AESZipFile(f'zip/{message.from_user.id}.zip','a') as create_zip_file:
            create_zip_file.write(random_img)
            create_zip_file.setpassword = create_password
```

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.setpassword) вы должны передавать параметр в метод `setpassword`. Строка должна выглядеть так

```py
.....
            create_zip_file.setpassword(create_password)
```

Comment: так пробовал, не помогло

Comment: что вы получаете на выходе? ошибки какие?

Comment: UserWarning: Duplicate name: 'photo/c8ik770a7ls41.jpg'
  return self._open_to_write(zinfo, force_zip64=force_zip64, pwd=pwd)